# How can you create more than one automated thank you for a donation?

Tags: donations, automation

We would like to set up a second thank you email to everyone who donates to our organization that is scheduled to go out 24 hours after the donation is made. It would be wonderful if it could include HTML formatting options and specific data tokens so that the letter is personal.

Thanks so much.

Comment: Have you had a look at what CiviRules and its companion extension for sending emails can do?

Comment: I don't know if you're already using Mosaico for your standard mailings but if not it's definitely worth exploring and some related extensions that allow you to use nicely branded templates in scheduled reminders ([Mosaico Message templates][1]) as well as system workflow messages ([Pretty workflow][2]). Scheduled reminders usually work well for automated emails based on a selection of entities, i.e. donations received.


  [1]: https://civicrm.org/extensions/mosaico-message-templates
  [2]: https://civicrm.org/extensions/pretty-workflow-messages

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried Schedule reminders?

Comment: Hi Pardeep, I think this would be better posted as a comment rather than an answer as it doesn't really answer the question.